# Remove spaces between patterns

Tags: bash, sed

I have a log file where data is separated by spaces. Unfortunately one of the datafields contains spaces as well. I would like to replace those spaces with "%20". It looks like this:

```
2012-11-02 23:48:36 INFO 10.2.3.23 something strange name.doc 3.0.0 view1 orientation_right
```

the expected result is

```
2012-11-02 23:48:36 INFO 10.2.3.23 something%20strange%20name.doc 3.0.0 view1 orientation_right
```

unpredictable that how many spaces we have between the IP address and ".doc". So I would like to change them between these two patterns using pure bash if possible.

thanks for the help

Comment: One query: So is the format going to be consistent? Is it safe to assume IP Address is followed by the data and then version (3.0.0 - similar format)?

Comment: yes, but the version number can be very different e.g. 2.9.9r232

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat file
2012-11-02 23:48:36 INFO 10.2.3.23 something strange name.doc 3.0.0 view1 orientation_right
```

Using Perl:

```
$ perl -lne 'if (/(.*([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3} )(.*)(.doc.*)/){($a,$b,$c)=($1,$3,$4);$b=~s/ /%20/g;print $a.$b.$c;}' file
2012-11-02 23:48:36 INFO 10.2.3.23 something%20strange%20name.doc 3.0.0 view1 orientation_right
```

Comment: @user1797649 : updated the solution by adding the option -l. Now it should not put all lines in one row.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\S*\s/&\n/4;s/\(\s\S*\)\{3\}$/\n&/;h;s/ /%20/g;H;g;s/\(\n.*\n\)\(.*\)\n.*\n\(.*\)\n.*/\3\2/' file
```

This splits the line into three, copies the line, replaces `space`'s with `%20`'s in one of the copies and reassembles the line discarding the unwanted pieces.

EDIT:

With reference to the comment below, the above solution can be ameliorated to:

```
sed -r 's/\S*\s/&\n/4;s/.*\.doc/&\n/;h;s/ /%20/g;H;g;s/(\n.*\n)(.*)\n.*\n(.*)\n.*/\3\2/' file
```

Comment: thanks, I have tested this and works! I forgot to mention that sometimes we have more than 3 column after the doc filename and hard to predict how many.

Answer (score 0):

Untested as of yet, but in Bash 4 it's possible to do this

```
if [[ $line =~ (.*([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+ +)([^ ].*\.doc)(.*) ]]; then
  nospace=${BASH_REMATCH[3]// /%20}
  printf "%s%s%s\n" ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} ${nospace} ${BASH_REMATCH[4]}
fi
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. unfortunatel this one did not give back any result.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way with GNU sed:

```
echo "2012-11-02 23:48:36 INFO 10.2.3.23 something strange name.doc 3.0.0 view1 orientation_right" |
sed -r 's/(([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+\s+)(.*\.doc)/\1\n\3\n/; h; s/[^\n]+\n([^\n]+)\n.*$/\1/; s/\s/%20/g; G; s/([^\n]+)\n([^\n]+)\n([^\n]+)\n(.*)$/\2\1\4/'
```

Output:

```
2012-11-02 23:48:36 INFO 10.2.3.23 something%20strange%20name.doc 3.0.0 view1 orientation_right
```

#### Explanation

```
s/(([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+\s+)(.*\.doc)/\1\n\3\n/  # Separate the interesting bit on its own line
h                                             # Store the rest in HS for later
s/[^\n]+\n([^\n]+)\n.*$/\1/                   # Isolate the interesting bit
s/\s/%20/g                                     # Do the replacement
G                                             # Fetched stored bits back
s/([^\n]+)\n([^\n]+)\n([^\n]+)\n(.*)$/\2\1\4/ # Reorganize into the correct order
```

Comment: thanks! this one double the lines and change the sapeces to %20 in every 2nd row. maybe I did something wrong

Comment: @user1797649: I suspect there are some tabs in your input, I've updated the answer to accommodate such input.

Answer (score 0):

A variation on Thor's answers, but using 3 processes (4 with the `cat` bellow but you can get rid of it by putting your_file as the last argument of the 1st sed):

```
cat your_file |
  sed -r -e 's/ (([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+) +(.*\.doc) / \1\n\3\n/' |
  sed -e '2~3s/ /%20/g' |
  paste -s -d "  \n"
```

As Thor explained:

- The 1st sed (`s/ (([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+) +(.*\.doc) / \1\n\3\n/`) separates the interesting bit on its own line.

And then:

- The 2nd sed replaces all spaces by `%20` on the 2nd line and every 3 lines.
- Finally, paste it back together.

It must be noted that the `2~3` part is a GNU sed extension.  If you do not have GNU sed, you can do:

```
cat your_file |
  sed -r -e 's/ (([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+) +(.*\.doc) / \1\n\3\n/' |
  sed -e 'N;P;s/.*\n//;s/ /%20/g;N' |
  paste -s -d "  \n"
```

Comment: thanks! this one copied the line and change all spaces to %20. maybe I missed something?

Comment: Which line did you copy ?  The one with the 2 sed and one paste or the one with a single sed ?  If it is the later, it was only given as a replacement for the 2nd sed if you do not have GNU sed.  I am updating the solution to be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Just bash. Assuming 4 fields appear before the space separated string and 3 fields appear after:

```
reformat_line() {
    local sep i new=""
    for ((i=1; i<=$#; i++)); do
        if (( i==1 )); then
            sep=""
        elif (( (1<i && i<=5) || ($#-3<i && i<=$#) )); then
            sep=" "
        else
            sep="%20"
        fi
        new+="$sep${!i}"
    done
    echo "$new"
}

while IFS= read -r line; do
    reformat_line $line    # unquoted variable here
done < filename
```

outputs

```
2012-11-02 23:48:36 INFO 10.2.3.23 something%20strange%20name.doc 3.0.0 view1 orientation_right
```